# Disabling validation in @Html.TextBoxFor in .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 3 . I've an entity called Student having the properties Id, Name, Age, RollNo. In the create page of Student, I've used validation framework. But in Advanced Search page I'm using all the properties but don't want to use validation framework as users may not want to use all the fields for searching.

I would also like to mention that I've used [Required] annotation in model class.

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Regards
Molay

Comment: use `Html.TextBox` instead? You will lose other goodness which `TextBoxFor` brings but they are not so hard to hardcode.

Comment: When you feel like that, then you suppose to consider ViewModel for this search page or any other custom page. After all ViewModels is always a best practice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would agree with xixonia, use a separate View Model for search but to answer your question you have a few options client side:

1. Pass in `data-val = "false"` as an HTML attribute, e.g: `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { data_val = "false" });`
2. Use `@Html.TextBox()` instead
3. Manually create your text box with HTML using the same input name so it binds to the model

If you're doing validation in the back end (you should be!), i.e. checking `ModelState.IsValid` then you will have to remove the validation properties from the ModelState, like so: `ModelState.Remove("Age");`.

Comment: I didn't think about doing that! :)

Answer (score 3):

Add this code on your form:

```
@Html.EnableClientValidation(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not remove attribute at run-time. You will have to have multiple view-models for student entity one for create and other for search.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the values of the Student class are restricted (as they should be).

I would consider using a separate view model for the search, rather than using a Student.

```
public class Student
{
    [ValidationAttributeOfSomeKind]
    int Age { get; set; }

    [ValidationAttributeOfSomeKind]
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class StudentSearch
{
    int? Age { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write your own textbox helper. There is no way to disable this.